# Recover deleted uls logs in a sharepoint farm older than number of days

Tags: 2010, uls, monitoring

there is any chance to get the logs before 15 days, as in diagnostic logging settings in a sharepoint 2010 farm is Number of days" for the log to be maintained
is 5 days .

Answer (score 1):

Once those files are deleted, they're gone. If you've set up the Usage Database, there may be additional information in the View `dbo.ULSTraceLog` which you can query directly via SQL Server Management Studio. It also depends on the number of days you've trimmed there.

Comment: HI, in this farm i setup the usage database,Here how to check the number of days trim usage logs?

Answer (score 1):

You could look into the WSS_Logging database, depending on how the logs were deleted, especially if you have SQL backups of WSS_Logging. Check out this link to read how to query it: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh769360(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Another Options, this only works, If you have the Windows server backup then you restore the files from the backup.

We have SharePoint Server backup, which will backup all the drives.

Comment: i checked in sharepoint server backup also there is no log files , i checked in one week past backup, is these uls logs save in  wss_logging database?

Comment: I am talking about the SharePoint backups rather the Server backup like all drives backup(c drive, d drive etc). if you have that then you can get old files.

Comment: sharepoint backups ? can you give some example? as i noticed in old vmware backup of server i did not found old dates backups? when i google i found http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointwarrior/archive/2012/10/11/sharepoint-2010-no-new-uls-logs-being-generated.aspx this article, can i get missed dates logs in temp folder?

Comment: sorry for the confusion...I am Not Talking about SharePoint Backups....But Server Backup...In my farm we have server backup, which backup the drives(whatever on it) every day. So if you have that backup then you can restores the logs from previous days.